# Drawer Navigator with Stack in React Native in Header

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a confusion regarding React Navigation. I need a Login screen which don't have Drawer and in rest of application, I need drawer Navigation.

I am looking for a solution where I can write code in a single place and applicable on whole application.

So I have created one stack navigator which contains the path of

```
 createStackNavigator({
  LoginRT:{
    screen:Login
  },
  HomeRT:{
    screen:Home
  },
  ContactRT:{
    screen:Contact,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerRight: (
        <Text></Text>
      )
    }
  },
 HaulerSelectionRT:{
    screen:HaulerSelection
  }

},
{
  initialRouteName: 'LoginRT',
  /* The header config from HomeScreen is now here */
  defaultNavigationOptions : ({ navigation}) => ({

    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#3B9EC1",
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 16, 

    },
    headerTitleStyle: {

      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 20,     
      textAlign:"center", 
        flex:1 

    },
    // headerRight: (
    //   <Icon
    //   size={30}
    //     name="bars"
    //     style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}
    //     onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
    //   />

   // ),
    // headerLeft: <Text onPress={() => 
    //   navigation.navigate('LoginRT')}>Menu</Text>,


    headerTintColor: "#fff",
    animationEnabled: true
  })
}
);
```

and one for Drawer Navigation

```
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    LoginRoute: Login,
    Hauler: HaulerSelection,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LoginRoute',
    drawerPosition: 'left',

  // navigationOptions: {navigationOptions

  //    },
   }
  );
```

and then I register both in Appcontainer

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MyRoutes,DrawerStack);
```

But DrawerNavigation is not working.

My doubt is, Is my approach is right? Or there is another way to achieve same.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The header part is added by default and is avoidable.
You can use the following code to achieve this.

```
 navigationOptions: {
        header: null
   }
```

This navigation options could either be screen specific or common to all screens.

Comment: Showing/Hiding  Header in other screen is fine, but when I am clicking Button on Header section Drawer Navigator is not appearing so First thing I need to confirm whether this approach is right or not?

Comment: Follow this 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html

Execute:
this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
(or)
this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
on button click